# Receiving the error in Opencv: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning

I'm currently using opencv to identify individuals on screen, and I've created a model, but I'm receiving this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

I've searched through numerous forums trying to find a solution, but none of them have really helped. Below is part of the card.

```
#Creates the video capture
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
camera.set(3, 650)  # Sets the camera width
camera.set(4, 480)  # Sets the camera height

# Creates the window size of for the face
minW = 0.1 * camera.get(3)
minH = 0.1 * camera.get(4)

face_module = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_module = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")

recogniser = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()  # This will rea the LBPH method
recogniser.read("/content/trainner/trainner.yml")  # This is where the YML file will be read


def getStudent(ID):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("FaceBase.db")
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE ID=" + str(ID)
    cursor = connection.execute(cmd)
    student=None
    for row in cursor:
        student=row
    connection.close()
    return student


df = pd.read_csv("attendance.csv")
columnNames = ["ID", "Full Name", "Major", "Time"]
attendance = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnNames)

# This is where the detection logic will occur
while (True):
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_module.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.5, 5)
```

Comment: Can you check whether `ret` is true, and print `frame.shape`?

Comment: @Burak Thanks for answering! I've updated the answer for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a two problems in the code shown above and one of them was the:

```
recogniser.read("/content/trainner/trainner.yml")
```

This came with an error about the path of the trainner file, but to fix that you need to implement the absolute path of this so it would be.

```
recogniser.read(r"/Users/...../Documents/....../trainner/trainner.yml")
```

And to fix the cv2Colour issue you will need to add in the code right below camera read

```
    if ret is True:
        #print("frame.shape")
    
    else:
         continue
```

Hope this helps someone out there!